# How to generate a list of lists from a given list following a rule recursively?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Assume that I have made the following rule: 
Rule:

> {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8}
> -> {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8},  {x4,x5,x6,x1,x2,x3,x7,x8}, {-x1,-x2,-x3,-x4,-x5,-x6,x7,x8}, {x1,-x2,x3,x4,-x5,x6,-x7,-x8}

For example, start with `{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8}` I want to generate the following lists recursively.

> {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8},
> {x4,x5,x6,x1,x2,x3,x7,x8}, {-x1,-x2,-x3,-x4,-x5,-x6,x7,x8}, {x1,-x2,x3,x4,-x5,x6,-x7,-x8}

Now for every newly-created list, I also want to apply the rule to generate new lists.
For example:
From `{x4,x5,x6,x1,x2,x3,x7,x8}` we can also generate `{-x4,-x5,-x6,-x1,-x2,-x3,x7,x8}` and `{ x4,-x5,x6,x1,-x2,x3,-x7,-x8}` which are not listed before.
This process should run until there is no new list which can generate from the rule. 
Result is to retun all lists which is possible to generate from the rule. 
This is a numerical example:

> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
> -> {4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8}, {-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,7,8}, {1,-2,3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8}

Now for every new list, for example, `{4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8}` I can also generate

> {-4,-5,-6,-1,-2,-3,7,8},  {4,-5,6,1,-2,3,-7,-8}

which are new.
This process is applied until there is no new list that is able generated using the rule.  
Result:

> {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8}, {-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,7,8},
> {1,-2,3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8},{-4,-5,-6,-1,-2,-3,7,8},
> {4,-5,6,1,-2,3,-7,-8},...}

How can I generate this?

Comment: Something like what `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}} /. {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_} :> Sequence[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}, {x4, x5, x6, x1, x2, x3, x7, x8}, {-x1, -x2, -x3, -x4, -x5, -x6, x7, x8}, {x1, -x2, x3, x4, -x5, x6, -x7, -x8}]` does?

Comment: @J.M. but this is not recursive. I want to apply this to every newly-generated list as well.

Comment: Then you can use `Nest[]` along with that previous suggestion, no?

Comment: @J.M. I don't know how many time to nest that. I want to do it until there is no new list to be create using this rule.

Comment: @emnha, ``NestWhile[]``?

Comment: @Domen it probably works but I'm not quite sure how to add the condition to know when it should be stopped.

Comment: You could check the ``Length``.  However, meanwhile I figured out that ``FixedPoint`` is a cleaner solution, so take a loot at user293787's answer.

Comment: I was hoping the suggestion to look at `Nest[]` would have led the OP to look at `NestWhile[]` and `FixedPoint[]` as well... o well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
rules = {x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_,x6_,x7_,x8_}:>{{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8},{x4,x5,x6,x1,x2,x3,x7,x8},{-x1,-x2,-x3,-x4,-x5,-x6,x7,x8},{x1,-x2,x3,x4,-x5,x6,-x7,-x8}};

(*apply once and remove duplicates*)
new[expr_]:=Union[Flatten[Map[(#/.rules)&,expr],1]];

(*apply repeatedly*)
newFixedPoint[expr_]:=FixedPoint[new,expr];
```

I uses `Union`, as suggested by @J.M.. It also uses [Fixedpoint](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html). Then say

```
newFixedPoint[{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}}]
```

gives

```
{{-4,-5,-6,-1,-2,-3,7,8},{-4,5,-6,-1,2,-3,-7,-8},
 {-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,7,8},{-1,2,-3,-4,5,-6,-7,-8},
 {1,-2,3,4,-5,6,-7,-8},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
 {4,-5,6,1,-2,3,-7,-8},{4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8}}
```

Comment: Nice, let me check if it can generate all possible lists.

Comment: I simplified it a little bit, but it should still give the same result as before.

Comment: Why are you using `Sort[DeleteDuplicates[xxx]]` and not `Union[xxx]`?

Comment: If you set `rules` to the `Sequence[]` version in the first comment under the OP, then `FixedPoint[Union[# /. rules] &, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}]` does the job.